# A PDF Reader for Windows that has a fullscreen flow-scroll mode

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer

Most PDF readers in full screen mode switch from one page to the next when you scroll in full screen. Is there one that scrolls "flowing" instead?

Answer (score 1):

Acrobat Reader does that.

In Reader, set View > Page Display > Enable Scrolling

Press CTRL+SHIFT+H

Press CTRL+L

FYI, you may have missed a setting in the other readers. Look for "Continuous" vs "Page" settings.